# Prolog: All digit Combinations

Tags: prolog

I'm doing an exercise in which given a number I should find all the combinations of digits of the number, given an M length.

For example if N = 1234, M = 3, Combinations = [[1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,4], [2,3,4]].

I don't understand how to obtain the combinations, maybe using a findall (in this case i don't understand how)?

This is the code that I have wrote to find the number (and combinations, but it print only [1,1,1])

```
all_digit_combinations(N, M, Combinations):-
    find_list_numbers(N, List),
    print(List),
    reverse(List, NewList),
    all_digit_combinations(N, M, NewList, Combinations).

all_digit_combinations(_N, M, List, Combinations):-
    length(Combinations, M),
    eval(Combinations, List).



find_list_numbers(N, [Last|R]):-
    N > 0,
    !,
    Last is N mod 10,
    Rest_Number is N div 10,
    find_list_numbers(Rest_Number, R).
find_list_numbers(_N, []).

eval([], _ListN).
eval([H|T], ListN):-
    member(H, ListN),
    eval(T, ListN).
```

Comment: What do you expect to get if there are repeating digits, for example, N = 111, M = 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate combinations, you can use the following code:

```
% combination(+List, +M, -Combination)

  combination(List, M, Combination) :-
     length(Combination, M),
     combination(List, Combination).

  combination(_, []).
  combination([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- combination(Xs, Ys).        % choose X, or
  combination([_|Xs], Ys) :- Ys \= [], combination(Xs, Ys).  % don't choose X
```

Running example:

```
?- combination([1,2,3,4], 3, C).
C = [1, 2, 3] ;
C = [1, 2, 4] ;
C = [1, 3, 4] ;
C = [2, 3, 4] ;
false.
```

To collect all solutions into a list, you can use `findall/3` as following:

```
?- findall(C, combination([1,2,3,4], 3, C), L).
L = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]].
```